# Assign file contents to variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file full of server names - one name per line. I need to read the contents of that file and assign the server name to a variable, complete a few commands, then do it again for the next server name. Here's what I've got so far:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%UserProfile%\Desktop\servers.txt) do (
    set server=%%a 
    set loc=%UserProfile%\Desktop\GPOResult_%server%
    gpresult /S %server% /H %loc% /F
)
```

And here's the output that I am getting from it when I turn echo off:

```
(
set server=<ServerName>
set loc=C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\GPOResult_
gpresult /S /H /F
)
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/S'
Type "GPRESULT /?" for usage.
```

So I guess my main issue is that the variables aren't sticking for whatever reason. Any help that can be provided would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks Guys

Comment: Woops, sorry forgot to include - that output, I get that for EACH server in the list. So it IS calling each line in the file as I expected it to, it's just not assigning the variable properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%UserProfile%\Desktop\servers.txt) do (
   set server=%%a 
   set loc=%UserProfile%\Desktop\GPOResult_!server!
   gpresult /S !server! /H !loc! /F
 )
```

Any time you set a variable inside a for block, you have to use delayed expansion to read it.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I'll have to remember that about For blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed Expansion is required when a *variable* change its value inside a `for` or `if` commands. However, in your case it is not necessary because %%a replaceable parameter is the part that change its value, that is to say, you don't require to use variables in your code:

```
set loc=%UserProfile%\Desktop\GPOResult_%%a
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%UserProfile%\Desktop\servers.txt) do (
    gpresult /S %%a /H %loc% /F
)
```

Or even simpler:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%UserProfile%\Desktop\servers.txt) do (
    gpresult /S %%a /H %UserProfile%\Desktop\GPOResult_%%a /F
)
```